# How can i fix this code that, when running, don't do anything?

Tags: c#, if-statement, variables

Well im trying to do a simple code in c# with nothing more than some if statements, but for some reason i don't understand the code compile but don't let me interact with. The console window keep black and when i press some key nothing happens.It should show the value of result (one or two dependent of the case).
The code:

```
        int result1;
        int result2;
        int delta = (b * b) - 4 * a * b;
        //Declaration of the variables results and delta, the ones that will be used in the following block
        if ((a != 0) && (b != 0) && (c != 0))
        {
            if (delta == 0)
            {
                result1 = (-b) / (2 * a);
                Console.WriteLine(result1);
            }
            else if (delta > 0)
            {
                result1 = (-b + Root(delta)) / (2 * a);
                result2 = (-b - Root(delta)) / (2 * a);
                Console.WriteLine(result1);
                Console.WriteLine(result2);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Sem resultado: delta menor que zero.");
            }
        }
        //In this if clause the code will verify the use of Bhaskara and the value of delta. Then execute the right count.
```

The "root" method up there is this one:

```
static int Root (int radi) 
    {
        int rootTester = 0;
        int result;
        for (; ;)
        {
            rootTester++;
            if(rootTester * rootTester != radi)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        result = rootTester;
        return result;
        //Here the compiler will try to multiplie a number for itself until this number will get equal the value of the radial
    }
```

The variables "a", "b" and "c" have respectively the values 1, -20 and 51.
I tried to change the delta declaration of place, but it doesn't worked.
How can i solve this problem?
(sorry if i said something wrong in english)

Comment: There's no code to interact with a console user in the code you provided.

Comment: Where did you define a and b? 
You might want to use `Console.ReadLine()` with appropriate conversion to "Interact with it"

Comment: You need to learn how to use [the debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019) to step through the code line by line. That way you can understand what it's doing.

Comment: Step through your code in the MSVS debugger.  If you don't know how to use the debugger - this is a great opportunity to *LEARN*.  That will show you *exactly* why you're "not seeing anything" ;)

Comment: Ohhhh thx guys i will try to use the visual studio debug feartures

Answer (score -1):

U forgot the
Console.ReadLine();

Comment: You need to give more info to them, say in which part of the code they forgot to put the Console.ReadLine();